# PHP array of non-primitive class as function parameter

Tags: php

I am wondering (if possible) how you would declare an array of non-primitive class as a function parameter. For example

```
<?php
class C {}

function f(array C $c) {
    /* use $c[1], $c[2]... */
}
```

Comment: There's no need to declare any type for `$c`, you can directly do `function f($c){ ... }`, given that `$c` is an array of *Class C* objects.

Comment: No way for this. Or create a class like `CCollection` which will store collection of `C` objects

Comment: you dont need to add "array" in your parameter. All you need to do is add what type of object you are passing, in this case is class C as so: `function f(C $c) { .. }`

Comment: @CodeGodie argument must be __array of C objects__

Comment: Ahh.. gotcha @u_mulder thanks for the clarificaion

Comment: @u_mulder so `function f(C $c) { .. }` will support both a C object and an array of C objects, or just an array of C objects?

Comment: No, it will not support arrays. Just object of type `C`

Comment: @u_mulder so the only way to get an array of objects would be a general `function f($c){ ... }` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main fact - **currently** you can't type hint argument as `array of something`.

So you options are:

```
// just a function with some argument, 
// you have to check whether it is array 
// and whether each item in this array has type `C`
function f($c) {} 

// function, which argument MUST be array.
// if it is not array - error happens
// you still have to check whether 
// each item in this array has type `C`
function f(array $c) {} 

// function, which argument of type CCollection
// So you have to define some class CCollection
// object of this class can store only `C` objects
function f(CCollection $c) {} 

// class CCollection can be something like
class CCollection 
{
    private $storage = [];

    function addItem(C $item)
    {
        $this->storage[] = $item;
    }

    function getItems()
    {
        return $this->storage;
    }
}
```

Comment: PHP7.1 supports an `iterable` type hint: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/iterable